# Angular error: newTree.optimize is not a function

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v9

I recently started getting this error when attempting to create a new component using the angular CLI:

```
newTree.optimize is not a function
```

the issued command was:

```
ng g c test
```

Googling return only articles from Angular CLI v6.x
I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Angular globally with no luck.
Here is my current versioning:

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
Angular CLI: 9.1.0
Node: 12.16.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...
Ivy Workspace:
Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.901.0
@angular-devkit/core         9.1.0
@angular-devkit/schematics   9.1.0
@schematics/angular          9.1.0
@schematics/update           0.901.0
rxjs                         6.5.4
```

has anyone else found a fix for this?

Thank you!

Comment: npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@6.1.0-rc.0

Comment: no, the current version of angular CLI is 9.0.1, I am not going back to 6.x. It is something else.

Comment: then must be your modules doesn't support angular 9

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After I upgraded to angular 9, I had 2 packages that were both still at version 0.6.8, They were:

```
@schematics/angular@9.1.0
@angular-devkit/schematics@9.1.0
```

For whatever reason, they were not upgraded and it resulted in this error.

Comment: I had both `@angular-devkit/schematics` and `@angular-devkit/core` on `0.6.8` only in `package-lock.json` didn't event had it installed. Really weird. Installed the dependencies as dev dependencies and everything is solved. Hours lost.

Answer (score 3):

The answer above was correct for me but I thought I'd expand on it, in case anyone else runs into the same issue...

```
@schematics/angular
@angular-devkit/schematics
@angular-devkit/core
```

were all on 0.6.8. Running the following resolved my issue:

```
npm install @schematics/angular
npm install @angular-devkit/schematics
npm install @angular-devkit/core
```

I hope this helps :)